# Selecting child node group with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I'm trying to use for-each to select and display a group of child nodes and I'm stuck!

XML

```
<cta>
    <text>Call to action text</text>
    <link>call to action link location</link>
    <alt>call to action alt text</alt>
    <target>_blank</target>
    <style>button blueBut</style>
</cta>
<cta>
    <text>Call to action 2</text>
    <link>call to action 2 link</link>
    <alt>call to action 2 alt text</alt>
    <target>_blank</target>
    <style>button blueBut</style>
</cta>
```

XSL

```
<div class="buttonPostLeft">    
    <xsl:for-each select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='Overview']/overview/cta/*">
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name='class'>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='Overview']/overview/cta/style" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name='href'>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='Overview']/overview/cta/link" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name='title'>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='Overview']/overview/cta/alt" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='Overview']/overview/cta/text"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

I Basically want the anchor tag to repeat for every cta group in the XML tree with that groups attributes. So in this example there would be 2 links within the DIV. Hope that makes a shred of sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your for-each, you are now looping through all child nodes of any matched `<cta>` by using `/cta/*`

You need to change

```
/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='Overview']/overview/cta/*
```

into

```
/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='Overview']/overview/cta
```

Also, once you're inside the for-each loop, you can match the elements inside the  by just using a dot, like so:

```
<xsl:attribute name='class'>
    <xsl:value-of select="./style" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

and even neater would be something like this:

```
<a class="{./style}" href="{./link}" title="{./alt}">
    <xsl:value-of select="./text"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that before however, this results in the first group being repeated twice rather than once for each group

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can read what the parenthesis tags actually do? I can't see it in my XSLT cookbook (I might be looking in the wrong place tbh)

Comment: it's just a shorthand for 'value-of' and the nice thing about it is that you can use it inside your HTML tags